# How to convert shape to Bezier curves in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, bezier-curve

If I draw rounded rectangle and rescale it

[image]

it will change non-uniformly. This is because it is not Bezier curve, but some algorithmic shape.

How to convert it to Bezier curve? (There was such command in Corel Draw).

Comment: I think you need to check `Scale Corners` in Transform panel. Select all your shapes and open Transform and check this option.

Answer (score 1):

The rounded Rectangle corners are already Bezier Curves. If you click an anchor with the Direct Selection Tool (White Arrow), it will show Bezier handles.

If you are scaling with the Bounding Box you  must use the shift key to scale proportionately. Even with Scale Corners checked in the Transform Panel and in Preferences> General- If you scale the shape non-proportionately it will not maintain the "Full Round/ Pill shape" you began with.

If you are scaling using the Scale Tool and Alt/Option clicking to scale using the numeric dialog box then scale uniformly and check the "Scale Corners" box.

You have to either scale uniformly or adjust the round rectangle corners after you have non-proportionately scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the checkbox on scale corners and that will fix it. ;)

[image]